# Excessive log throttling on Azure SQL on business critical tier

Tags: azure-sql-database

We moved from the Biz Critical vCore Gen4_8 tier to Gen5_8 over the holidays. We had to move because our log growth is constantly pushing us into the 1 TB limit of Gen4.  Not only are our queries taking twice as long in Gen5, but we are seeing a lot of log rate throttles as shown here:

[image]

Why are there three different log rate throttles - what is the difference between them?  If you remove the non-important CXCONSUMER wait, almost half of our waits are from the 3 throttles.

I can reproduce the log rate throttles with nothing else running in our pool with a simple "SELECT TOP 20000000 * INTO newtable FROM oldtable" query.  We are selecting from a very narrow table (4 int and 2 float columns) that has a CCI and no fragmentation.

[image]

We contacted support and they responded with "its because of poor indexing or a very inefficient query plan". Obviously, there is nothing wrong with this query. It runs in 1:50 on Gen5 consistently, 49 secs in Gen4, and 20 secs on my old laptop.

When I run this query, the DMVs show the I/O for this query as: total_logical_writes=150258, total_physical_reads=44080.

Given that it takes 110 seconds to run, can we then say that each write and read is a single I/O which would make our average IOPS about 1766 ((150258+44080)/110)?   If not, is there a good way to measure how many IOPS a query hits?  I bring this up because the DB limit for Gen5_8 shows "Target IOPS" = 20000, but I think we are well below that.  Also is "target" an actual limit or an estimate of the throughput we could expect?

We never had throttling under Gen4 and are paying $50k a year for this service tier and our app is barely usable now - any suggestions/thoughts on where we go from here would be much appreciated!

Comment: What did they say when you show how gen 4 performs better than gen 5?

Comment: After my 5th email response to them trying to get clarification on this and the questions I listed above, they finally responded yesterday with "Gen4_8 has 40,000 Target IOPS, Gen5_8 has 20,000 Target IOPS. Difference in performance is certainly expected.".  Thats the only question they addressed. They didn't explain whether this applied to data or log I/O.  They also wouldn't explain why they say "Target" for this in the vcore model, while for every other pricing model in Azure they list "data throughput" and "log throughput", which are  clearly limits.

Answer (score 1):

After a few weeks with the Azure product team we have great answers to these questions.

The main bottleneck in Azure for us is Log I/O.  Each logical processor has 6 MB/s throughput. So, on Gen4_8, we have 16 logical processors and get 96 MB/s log I/O throughput. On Gen5_8, there are 8 processors so the throughput is 48 MB/S.

The reason for these limits is that if they allowed higher log I/O throughput they wouldn't be able to guarantee that the log shipping job that runs every 5 minutes would be able to capture all the transactions that occurred.

There is also a major issue with using MAXDOP on Azure right now.  By adding MAXDOP 1 to the SELECT INTO statements and our parallel inserts, our performance improved tremendously.  Do NOT use MAXDOP 8 or higher on Gen4 or Gen5! I tested on Gen5_16 and MAXDOP 8 adds a 10 fold increase to run times.   On Gen4_8, our production pool, our parallel insert for loading 1 billion records goes from 40 minutes with MAXDOP 1 to 3.5 hours with MAXDOP 8 (yes, which means we aren't really doing a parallel insert).